# No desktop icons after uninstalling nemo

Tags: nautilus, icons, nemo, desktop-icons

I tested nemo on Ubuntu 12.04. I made it the default file manager. When I uninstalled it, desktop icons disappeared and I can't do a right click on desktop to open menu.

How can I make Nautilus the default file manager, may this solve the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with launching `dconf-editor` then go to:

org -> gnome -> desktop -> background

and put the tick on `show-desktop-icons` as explained in the image below:

[image: dconf editor window with show desktop icons option]

Answer (score 3):

I was with the same problem as yours. Besides Michele tips, I also tried:

```
xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false
```

Answer (score 2):

To make Nautilus the default manager,  make sure that Nautilus is installed, if not you can install it.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adabbas/1stppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

Once its done, install a package called Exo Utilities.  To install:

```
sudo apt-get install exo-utils
```

Once its done, run it by typing in terminal:

```
exo-preferred-applications
```

When it opens, click on the utilities tab, and make sure that nautilus is chosen as the preferred file manager, and then click close.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.
I did what you have mentioned, but, same problem I can't see desktop icons.

Comment: @Nas Did you reboot?

Comment: Thanks, problem solved by checking show-desktop-icons as @Michele has explained.