# Change K3B behavior when clicking "Open File Manager"

Tags: kde, cinnamon, filemanager, k3b, nemo

When right clicking a file in K3B and clicking `Open File Manager` it attempts to open the file in Sublime Text (my default text editor). I need it to open in Nemo (my default file manager). Is there a way to change this setting?

Comment: Look at my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/301089/no-desktop-icons-after-uninstalling-nemo/301260#301260), see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

k3b uses the default file manager for KDE.  Make sure that Nemo is set as your default file manager:

1. Open up system-settings and start the Default Applications panel.
2. Choose File Manager in the list on the left and make sure Nemo is selected as your default file manager.
3. Click Apply

Files should now open up using Nemo when you right click a file from k3b and choose Open File Manager.

Comment: I would like to point out that I am running Ubuntu not Kubuntu so I did first have to download KDE System Settings but after doing that this did work. Thanks